# How to create non blocking consumer with amqp library

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using amqp module with RabbitMQ. I needed to create a non blocking consumer. For that purpose I used threading module.

There is one problem: I must make threads stopped on app exit. Here is the part of the code:

```
c.start_consuming(message_callback)

while not self._stop.isSet():

    if self._stop.isSet():
        print("thread will be stopped")
    else:
        print("thread will NOT BE STOPPED")

    c.channel.wait()
```

Problem is, c.channel.wait() sometime blocks and sometime not depending on whether there are some messages in the queue it is listening or not (I did some experiments but they are not enough)

If there were a timeout argument I could use with c.channel.wait() function, I could achieve that goal by setting the timeout, for example 0.1 seconds. As far as I search the source code, there is no timeout option.

Main Question: How can I create a non-blocking consumer with amqp module?

Sub Question 1: How can I patch the amqp code so it starts using a timeout value?

Fallback solution: I may consider using multiprocessing module in order to kill that process anytime.

Comment: Send it a 'Terminate now' message on the c channel.